# Is it viable to use sharer.php?

Tags: facebook, share

Ok so I know sharer.php URL has been deprecated for a while now, in favour of the social plugins.

However, one of the nice advantages (for us) of sharer.php was that we didn't have to create a Facebook App to obtain an ID to use in the SDK init calls.

On a project I'm working on the client is already using the sharer.php route, and they do not have an FB app for me to use.

So my question is, assuming sharer.php still works (and it seems to) does anyone have a clue if this functionality is threatened to disappear at any point soon? Or at all? I see no reference to it in the roadmap.

I'm not asking for best practices or anything like that because I wouldn't generally use a deprecated feature but if it's there, already being used, and works/will continue to work then I'm certainly going to consider it.

Cheers!

Comment: I've since discovered that mobile browsers don't work with sharer.php - at least not using the same URL to share as on desktop. Another nail in the coffin.

Answer (score 2):

From what I am seeing, `sharer.php` has stopped working now for some people.

If you are developing something new, you should use the [Like Button Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) instead of a deprecated endpoint.

Yes, you'll need to create an app for them, but this is trivial.

Comment: Oh you're actually seeing sharer.php stop working? Very interesting, I wonder how wide spread this is. Seems odd that it would only stop working for some people too. Thanks for your reply.